# Where are the links in the SE banner?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

We have the following arrangement across the top:

[image: SE banner with links]

However, when I logged in earlier today, I got this (I was logged in as I could post comments, etc):

[image: SE banner without links]

I've seen this happen a few times. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried a hard refresh?

Comment: Yes (CTRL + F5). It didn't work before I posted this question.

Comment: I closed my web browser, got your notification a few mins ago, and found the banner to be normal again. It seems to be hit or miss.

Comment: And I just tried it again (from meta sports to sports) and blank banner comes up again. Another hard refresh doesn't do the trick. Using IE8, FYI.

Comment: @edmastermind29: I would consider asking this again on http://meta.stackoverflow.com. You'll get more visibility on there.

Comment: @Matt Funny thing is....it doesn't happen on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/). But perhaps a flag for migration?

Comment: Meh, I wouldn't flag it, I'd just ask it again and delete this one. It might be worth trying a different browser (Chrome?) to see if it's just IE related or not.

Comment: Yeah....but even with IE, it's hit or miss, so I'll try a different browser and see if it duplicates.

Comment: Just to be clear, does it happen only when clicking the "Main" link at the top of Meta or does it happen when visiting the main site directly?

Comment: It also happens when visiting the main site directly.

Comment: Can you try other beta sites, like [history.se] or [libraries.se]?

Comment: Same thing on [History](http://history.stackexchange.com/)....blank banner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found out what's going on.

When compatibility mode on ***IE 8+*** is **off**, then the banner appears as normal.

When compatibilitiy mode is **on**, the banner disappears.